# Neo4j apoc.path.subgraphAll returning filtered out relationships

Tags: neo4j

I've got a neo4j database populated with a single type of nodes, and 4 types of edges loaded like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nearness_edges.csv" AS row
MERGE (t:Well {API: toInteger(row.API1)})
MERGE (f:Well {API: toInteger(row.API2)}) 
MERGE (t)<-[:Relation {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), ParSib: row.Relation}]-(f)
MERGE (t)<-[:Direction {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), LftRgt: row.Side}]-(f)
MERGE (t)<-[:Bench {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), AboSamBel: row.Bench}]-(f)
MERGE (t)<-[:near {Distance: toFloat(row.Dist), ParSib: row.Relation, LftRgt: row.Side, AboSamBel: row.Bench}]-(f)
```

I want to display the subgraph for a specific node, and am using this:

```
match (w:Well {API: 3302502276})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(w, {relationshipFilter: "near"})
YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships;
```

It's yielding the correct nodes, but *also* yeilding all edges connecting these nodes, rather than only the "near" type edges specified in the relationship filter. I.e. i expect this [image: expected] but obtain this [image: obtained] The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/graph-querying/expand-subgraph/) shows that I'm using the function correctly, and also shows in the example that the other relationships are filtered out as I'm expecting in my case. Looking at the table view of the results, we see that the function is returning other types of edges. In the screenshot here, the green highlighted edges are of type `Relation`, not `near`.[image: returned table]

The only way I could get the expected picture was by temporarily deleting the other edges, which is clearly not optimal.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the filter correctly. You are receiving these relationships in your result, because these nodes share these other relationships as well. Your filter just ensures that your subgraph matches.

```
CREATE (a:Test {id:'testa'})
CREATE (b:Test {id:'testb'})
CREATE (a)-[:REL_A]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:REL_B]->(b)
RETURN a, b
```

Yields all shared relationships (even though we only specified one):

```
MATCH (a:Test {id:'testa'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(a, {relationshipFilter: "REL_A"})
YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

When working with a simpler subgraph without multiple relationships between nodes, the apoc call works as previously assumed.

```
CREATE (a:Test2 {id:'test2a'})
CREATE (b:Test2 {id:'test2b'})
CREATE (c:Test2 {id:'test2c'})
CREATE (a)-[:REL_A]->(b)<-[:REL_B]-(c)
RETURN a, b, c
```

There will be no REL_B relationships in the response:

```
MATCH (a:Test2)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(a, {relationshipFilter: "REL_A"})
YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

Comment: This will show *all* connecting edges for the returned nodes. I thought it was clear that I want only the edges specified by the `relationshipFilter`. Further, in the documentation for the function, the example has multiple types of edges, and the function is returning (and the browser displaying) only the filtered for edges. I've edited the post to hopefully make the issue and expectation more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tested the behavior and came up with two examples that illustrates what is happening.

Comment: OK, yes I see that. The example in the documentation for the function which I cited only showed "KNOWS" edges because the selected nodes only had them. So how can I modify the call to return only the "near" edge types?